# How to use xtabs in a user defined function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a wrapper for `xtabs` with a custom function.

I tried doing this:

```
xtabs_fun <- function(data, variable) {
  xtabs(~ variable, data = data)
}
```

But using it doesn't return the correct value.

```
xtabs_fun(mtcars, "cyl")
```

```
cyl
1
```

The expected output should be this:

```
xtabs(~ cyl, data = mtcars)
```

```
cyl
 4   6   8
11   7  14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `reformulate`

```
xtabs_fun <- function(data, variable) {
    xtabs(reformulate(variable), data = data)
}
```

-testing

```
> xtabs_fun(mtcars, "cyl")
cyl
 4  6  8 
11  7 14
```

Answer (score 3):

`xtabs` accepts a data frame so:

```
xtabs_fun <- function(data, variable) xtabs(data[variable])

# test
xtabs_fun(mtcars, "cyl")
## cyl
##  4  6  8 
## 11  7 14
```

Alternately use `table` which works the same:

```
table_fun <- function(data, variable) table(data[variable])
```

Answer (score 2):

Variable names inside formulas are always taken literally rather than being substituted, so inside your function, `xtabs` is looking for a column called `variable` inside `mtcars`, which doesn't exist. Instead, you can build the formula as a string:

```r
xtabs_fun <- function(data, variable) {
  xtabs(as.formula(paste("~", variable)), data = data)
}

xtabs_fun(mtcars, "cyl")
#> cyl
#>  4  6  8 
#> 11  7 14
```

If you prefer your function to take unquoted variable names in a tidyverse style, you can do

```r
xtabs_fun <- function(data, variable) {
  xtabs(as.formula(paste("~", deparse(substitute(variable)))), data = data)
}

mtcars |> xtabs_fun(cyl)
#> cyl
#>  4  6  8 
#> 11  7 14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>